# Error while trying to run ipython3 notebook server on Ubuntu

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I followed the [instructions](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/notebook/public_server.html#notebook-public-server) for setting up ipython3 server.

Here is my `ipython_notebook_config.py`:

```
c.NotebookApp.ip = '*'
c.NotebookApp.certfile = u'/home/ed/.ipython/profile_default/ds.pem'
c.NotebookApp.open_browser = False
c.NotebookApp.password = u'sha512:..mykey...'
c.NotebookApp.port = 20000
```

When I start the notebook this is what I get:

```
ipython3 notebook                                                                                 ~
[I 19:51:50.443 NotebookApp] Using MathJax from CDN: https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js
[I 19:51:50.476 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /home/ed
[I 19:51:50.476 NotebookApp] 0 active kernels 
[I 19:51:50.476 NotebookApp] The IPython Notebook is running at: https://[all ip addresses on your system]:20000/
[I 19:51:50.476 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation)
```

When I try to connect to this machine from outside I get an error:

```
[E 19:52:02.413 NotebookApp] Exception in callback (<socket.socket fd=5, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=2049, proto=6, laddr=('0.0.0.0', 20000)>, <function wrap.<locals>.null_wrapper at 0x7f766269a488>)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/ed/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 866, in start
        handler_func(fd_obj, events)
      File "/home/ed/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 275, in null_wrapper
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/ed/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tornado/netutil.py", line 265, in accept_handler
        callback(connection, address)
      File "/home/ed/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tornado/tcpserver.py", line 239, in _handle_connection
        do_handshake_on_connect=False)
      File "/home/ed/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tornado/netutil.py", line 501, in ssl_wrap_socket
        context = ssl_options_to_context(ssl_options)
      File "/home/ed/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tornado/netutil.py", line 478, in ssl_options_to_context
        context.load_cert_chain(ssl_options['certfile'], ssl_options.get('keyfile', None))
    ssl.SSLError: [SSL] PEM lib (_ssl.c:2536)
```

I have set this on two other machines and I had no problems. I have no idea what's wrong, perhaps a missing library or some subtitle error that I can't see.

I'm using IPython 3.2.1., Python 3.4.3 on Ubuntu 15.04.

Any ideas?

Comment: seems like a ssl error you should check the certs and keys

Answer (score 0):

Using the revised opessl command

```
openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout mycert.key -out mycert.pem
```

from @GeQi and making sure to use HTTPS in the browser work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Check 1 : Update inbound rules in AWS EC2 Security Group for 22, 443, 8888.

Check 2: Make sure you create mycert.pem file in certs folder with following command:

> $ openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout
>   mycert.pem -out mycert.pem

Check 3: passwd() > Save SHA key & Add that key in jupyter_notebook_config.py

check 4: use https://public-DNS-of-EC2-Instance:8888
& proceed to advanced if connection is not private...

For more details: 
https://github.com/prakashpy/miscellaneous/tree/master/jupyter-notebook-on-aws-ec2

Answer (score -1):

> Jupyter and the future of IPython
>
> IPython is a growing project, with increasingly language-agnostic components. IPython 3.x was the last monolithic release of IPython, containing the notebook server, qtconsole, etc. As of IPython 4.0, the language-agnostic parts of the project: the notebook format, message protocol, qtconsole, notebook web application, etc. have moved to new projects under the name Jupyter. IPython itself is focused on interactive Python, part of which is providing a Python kernel for Jupyter.

In short, the notebook is no longer a part of the IPython project, thus you should look for the keywords of "Jupyter notebook". It's rather easy to switch to the newer Jupyter notebook, simply follow the doc (from [here](http://jupyter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) or [here](http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)) to install the module and [set up the public server](http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.org/en/latest/public_server.html). The procedure is almost identical. However, after finishing all that I still encounter the same SSLError. I've found the solution [here](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/507) in the github repo:

> It worked for me after making a slight change in the openssl parameters. i am saving both the key and certificate in the same file, 'mycert.pem'.
> original: `$ openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout mycert.key -out mycert.pem`
> my version: `$ openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout mycert.pem -out mycert.pem`

Some have reported that this wouldn't work out for them and the issue isn't closed yet, though this works perfectly for me. Also, you may want to clean up the former config.

```
# remove the earlier created ipython profile
$ ipython profile locate nbserver
/home/ubuntu/.ipython/profile_nbserver
$ rm -r /home/ubuntu/.ipython/profile_nbserver
$ ipython profile locate nbserver
[ProfileLocate] CRITICAL | Profile 'nbserver' not found.
```